# When I minimize the window and restore it again the window has a black background, I can't figure out why

Tags: c++, winapi, window, minimize, redraw

I'm new in programming Windows Application, and I have simple window with some checkboxes, text and button. Everything seems to work as it should, but when I minimize the window and restore it again the window has a black background, I can't figure out why.

### MY WINDOW CLASS:

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define CHECK_BOX1 1
#define CHECK_BOX2 2
#define Button_Submit_Checkboxes 3

HMENU hMenu;
HWND hText;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL checked1 = IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, 1);
    BOOL checked2 = IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, 2);
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:            
    switch (wParam)
        { // When clicked on Checkbox1, then check or uncheck.
            case CHECK_BOX1:
                if (checked1) 
                {
                    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
                }
            else {
                    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
                }
            break;

            case CHECK_BOX2:
            if (checked2) {
                CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 2, BST_UNCHECKED);
            }
            else {
                CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 2, BST_CHECKED);
            }
            break;

        case Button_Submit_Checkboxes: // Button_Submit_Checkboxes
            SetWindowTextW(hText, L"ssss");
            bool check[2];
            check[0] = checked1;
            check[1] = checked2;
            std::cout << "\ncheck1 : " << check[0] << "\ncheck2 : " << check[1];
            break;
    }
    break;

        case WM_CLOSE: // If window is closed
        DestroyWindow(hWnd); // destroy window.
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: // When window is destroyed.
        PostQuitMessage(0); // Send message to Windows.
        return 0;
    }

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

Window::Window()
    : m_hInstance(GetModuleHandle(nullptr)) 
{
    const wchar_t* CLASS_NAME = L"Siggis Window Class"; 

    WNDCLASS wndClass = {};
    wndClass.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wndClass.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO); // icon !!
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); // cursor !!
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc; 

    RegisterClass(&wndClass);

    DWORD style = WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU; 

    int width = 440;
    int height = 300;

    RECT rect;
    rect.left = 250;
    rect.top = 250;
    rect.right = rect.left + width;
    rect.bottom = rect.top + height;

    AdjustWindowRect(&rect, style, false);

    m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
    L"MFM - Ver. 1.00", // window title.
    style,
    rect.left,
    rect.top,
    rect.right - rect.left,
    rect.bottom - rect.top,
    NULL,
    NULL,// this is for menu!!
    m_hInstance,
    NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW); // Display window.

    AddMacMakeDisplay(m_hWnd); // show text and Edit window
}

Window::~Window()
{
    const wchar_t* CLASS_NAME = L"Siggis Window Class";

    UnregisterClass(CLASS_NAME, m_hInstance);
}

bool Window::ProcessMessages()
{
    MSG msg = {};

    while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0u, 0u, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {
        return false;
    }

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return true;
}


void Window::AddMacMakeDisplay(HWND hWnd)
{
    const int text_chkbox_left = 100;
    const int text_chkbox_top = 50;
    const int text_chkbox_width = 230;
    const int text_chkbox_height = 20;
    hText = CreateWindowExW(NULL, 
    L"static", 
    L"Choose : ", 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER, 
    text_chkbox_left,
    text_chkbox_top,
    text_chkbox_width,
    text_chkbox_height,
    hWnd, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    NULL);


// Checkbox Group Postion and Size
    const int chkbox_left = text_chkbox_left;
    const int chkbox_top = text_chkbox_top + text_chkbox_height+2;
    const int chkbox_width = text_chkbox_width;
    const int chkbox_height = 30;
// Create Checkbox1
    CreateWindowExW(NULL, 
        TEXT("button"), 
        TEXT("check1"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
    chkbox_left, 
    chkbox_top, 
    chkbox_width, 
    chkbox_height,
    hWnd, 
    (HMENU)CHECK_BOX1, 
    NULL, 
    NULL);
    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 1, BST_CHECKED); // Checkbox1 statues (checked or unchecked)       
// Create Checkbox2
    CreateWindowExW(NULL,
        TEXT("button"), 
    TEXT("Check2"), 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
    chkbox_left, 
    chkbox_top+chkbox_height, 
    chkbox_width, 
    chkbox_height,
    hWnd, 
        (HMENU)CHECK_BOX2, 
    NULL, 
    NULL);
    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 2, BST_CHECKED); // Checkbox2 statues (checked or unchecked)


// Button_Submit_Checkboxes Position and Size
    const int button_left = text_chkbox_left;
    const int button_top = chkbox_top + (2* chkbox_height) + 30;
    const int button_width = text_chkbox_width;
    const int button_height = 50;
// Create Button_Submit_Checkboxes
    CreateWindowExW(NULL,
        L"Button",
        L"Change Title",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        button_left,
        button_top,
        button_width,
        button_height,
        hWnd,
    (HMENU)Button_Submit_Checkboxes,
    NULL,
    NULL);
}
```

### This is my Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Window.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Creating Windows\n";

    Window* pWindow = new Window();

    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        if (!pWindow->ProcessMessages())
        {
            std::cout << "Closing Window\n";
            running = false;
        }
        // render
    
        Sleep(10);
    }

    delete pWindow;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to google the problem but without any luck. So I hope you can help me.

Comment: 2 messages you might want to handle [`WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) and [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint)

Comment: Small note: There's no point to using `new Window()` and then `delete pWindow` here. It can simply be `Window window;` with C++ destroying the object at the end of the function automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not filling in `wndClass.hbrBackground`. According to the documentation:

> When this member is `NULL`, an application must paint its own background whenever it is requested to paint in its client area. To determine whether the background must be painted, an application can either process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message or test the `fErase` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure filled by the `BeginPaint` function.

If you want Windows to handle this for you, pass a valid handle or a colour-plus-one:

```
wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! For now I just want windows to handle it, and it worked putting "wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);" into my Class. So thanks again :)